# mod_rewrite redirects with absolute path in URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pcre

I am trying to use Apache **mod_rewrite**. The first thing I did was to rewrite my url to an `index.php` file which was working fine. But I thought I should remove the trailing slash(es) too because I would prefer this to be handled by Apache instead of my PHP router.

Here's the whole content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# one of the attempts to remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]

# This is the rewriting to my index.php (working)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

---

**The issue:**
I read several questions about trailing slash removal but I could not find a working answer for me:
For every answer I tried, I was able to reach my PHP router `index.php` (located in `Phunder\public\`) without trailing slash:

```
// Requested URL                                | No redirection
http://localhost/projects/Phunder/public/home   | http://localhost/projects/Phunder/public/home
```

But when requesting the same page with a trailing slash I get redirected with the absolute path included:

```
// Requested URL                                | Wrong redirection
http://localhost/projects/Phunder/public/home/  | http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/Phunder/public/home
```

---

**Other informations:**

- I always clear my cache while testing
- Changing my last **RewriteRule** to `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?/$1 [L]` results in a **404 Error** with URL having a trailing slash.
- The actual wrong redirection results in a **403 Error**

I'm a beginner with mod_rewrite I'm not always understanding what I try (sadly). Is there something I missed or misused ? What should I do to get the expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect rules need either absolute URL or a `RewriteBase`. You can extract full URI from `%{REQUEST_URI}` as well like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# one of the attempts to remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/+$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# This is the rewriting to my index.php (working)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works, thanks ! But I don't completely understand the RewriteRule. I understand that `%1` refers to the capture group we get in the previous line but what does `^ %1` mean ? I'll do researches myself to understand the `NE` flag.

Comment: `^` is a regex with just start anchor that always matches. `%1` is back-reference of value being captured in `RewriteCond`. `NE` flag is for no-escape of URI after redirect.

Comment: Oh right, that's great. Thanks a lot I fully understand it now